# Running commands for docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

This is how I'm running a command in a docker container:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name myapp myimage:latest
$ node --version
```

Is it possible to to run this as one command? Can I pass a command to the `docker run`-command?

Something like

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name myapp myimage:latest "node --version"
```

Of course this is just a simple example. Later I will execute some more complex commands...

Comment: Would "docker exec" solve your problem? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general form of the command is actually:

> docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]

See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) for more details.

The answer to the minimal example in your question is simply:

```
docker run -it --rm --name myapp myimage:latest node --version
```

If you want to run multiple commands in sequence, you can:

1. Run container
2. Execute your commands against the running container using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)
3. Remove it

Answer (score 1):

The "docker run" command essentially will make the container run, and execute the "CMD" or "ENTRYPOINT" in the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/). Unless - the command in your dockerfile does not run a command prompt - "running" the container may not get you the prompt.

For example if you want that everytime you run the container - it gets you the command prompt then have the line below in your Dockerfile.:

```
CMD ["bash"]
```

If you want to run the same commands everytime you run the command - then you could create a script file with your commands, copy them to the container, and execute the script file as a CMD directive.

Answer (score 0):

I am having some trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

you can just :
docker run -d --name myapp myimage:latest -f /dev/null and then your container is up and you can run any command in it

you can pass a command to the docker run but once the command ends the container will exit

Comment: I want to call a testing script. But the config files are changing. So I would copy the config file to the container and then call the script which needs a parameter.

Comment: add flag -v /host/directory:/container/directory and in the directory put the script you want to run. at the end of the docker command you specify what command will run at the entry point so you can specify your script

Comment: Keep in mind this creates a volume for your container. This is an overkill if you only want to copy a file. Use "docker cp"  instead.